# Excel Conditional formatting whole table color code

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I would like to create a condition for my whole table.

I have three categories (i.e R, G, B).

If the first column (example: A1) is R, the rest of the ROW (ex: B1:E1) should be colored with red. If G, then green, and if B, then Blue.

What I've done so far is I've selected my work area which is B1:E1, then clicked on conditional formatting > new rule > "Use a formula to determine which cell to format" (I'm using excel 2010). Then Typed this at the formula bar =SEARCH("R", $A$1)>0. It does change the color of B1:E1, however, I don't know how to do this for my whole table. If I select my whole table, and A1 is equal to R or G or B, the whole table change its color to whatever the value of A1. I also change my formula to =SEARCH("R", $A$1:$A$120)>0 which is the range of my table, still doesn't work. I've also created 3 conditions for each color with same formula (I just changed the letter R to G and B), still does not work.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were actually pretty close, just change

```
=SEARCH("R", $A$1)>0
```

to

```
=SEARCH("R", $A1)>0
```

so the conditional formatting rule will always look for "R" in the current row rather than row 1.
You should have this rule apply to the whole range that may be colored (I'm guessing B1:E120)

Also, you can make two rules for your other colors using the same approach.

Comment: ya, I was able to figure it out and change my formula to make it search the exact word. i.e =SEARCH("R", $A$1:$A$120)>0 was changed to =$A1:$A120="R". Then 2 more of this formula for the other colours.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, I recommend using the above code - it does the same work but is clearer. Would you please accept the answer if it's correct? Thanks ;)

Comment: I already accepted it. There's a message that says about those who have below 15 reputation blah blah :D. Also, I have another question if you don't mind. Is it possible to write a text using conditional formatting? What I'm trying to do is I want all blank cells to change the color to "Gray" and display a text saying "No Data Found". I hope it's possible. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you can insert text using conditional **formatting**. You can, however, check for empty cells with the formula =ISBLANK(A1).

Comment: ya, but how can you do it for all the cells? I mean, I already have a table, so what if I add an additional record that has an empty cell? Is it possible using a formula? Thanks again.

Comment: Select the whole column A, then add a conditional formatting rule, use "=ISBLANK(A1)", choose format grey.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. If I select the whole column A, then do the =isblank(A1), would the format read it like "if A1 is blank, then gray out the whole column A". Is that correct? Or will it read it like "if any of the cell in column A is blank, gray it out".

Comment: Since there are no dollars ($), "A1" is a relative reference (it will always reference the current cell, not actually A1). Therefore, any cell that is blank itself will be turned to grey.